# Почему count возвращает постоянно 1?

Tags: laravel, postgresql

сам запрос
`select count(*) as aggregate from "products" group by "products"."id"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы делаете `INNER JOIN` и хотите еще сделать `COUNT(*)`, чтобы получить число всех строк в одном запросе - много хотите. Для этого нужно выполнить два запроса. Вот пример, вам нужно поместить свой основной запрос вместе с JOIN'ами и всем чем хотите в запрос для подсчета результата:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
    SELECT * FROM products
    INNER JOIN table2 ON products.id = table2.id
    GROUP BY products.id
)
```

Comment: хмм... странно
с postgres впервый раз, с mysql как-то проще было

Answer (score 0):

GROUP BY - Группирует вам `id` и возвращает число сколько было найдено совпадений в СТОЛБЦЕ.
То-есть:

```
Строка 1 - id = 1
Строка 2 - id = 2
Строка 3 - id = 1
```

Результат GROUP BY:

```
Строка 1 - 2
Строка 2 - 1
```

В вашем же случае `id` - уникально и одинаковые значения не допустимы. Просто уберите `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `aggregate` FROM `products`;
```

Comment: тонда неправильно считает, так как я делаю inner join еще, и возвращает дубли записей, группировка по id решает ету проблему, но с count не работает почему-то

Comment: @VanyaGuk это уже другой вопрос, нужно сразу было об этом говорить в вопросе

Comment: вот сейчас такая проблема